# Enable Log file for receiving push notifications on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have nearly no experience with iOS (9.1) devices.
I need to test an app that receives push notification (APNS).
The environment is set up in a way that every 2-3 minutes a push is triggered and this should be received by the iPhone.

I haven't found a possibility yet to log the incomming pushes on the iPhone. The MessageCenter only shows a limited number of pushes.

**Is there a possibility to enable logging in iOS to write information about incomming pushes to a file?**

I have found [this](http://atnan.com/blog/2009/07/27/enabling-verbose-push-notification-service-apns-logs/) site, but the links to Apple’s developer forums does not work any more. Also installing the `*.mobileconfig` mentioned on that page directly from Safari does not work.

**EDIT:**
Here is the error that appears on trying to load the *.mobilconfig from the avove mentioned page. (translated from german by me. Original text my be different)

> **Profile cannot be installed.** Safari could not install the profile
>   (unknown error)